# updating table in Spring Data JPA with composite key

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I have following table with structure as below-

APARTMENT_REVIEW table

APARTMENT_REVIEW_ID (auto_increment)
CUSTOMER_ID
APARTMENT_ID
REVIEW_TEXT

One customer can review one apartment once. Hence, CUSTOMER_ID+APARTMENT_ID combination is a composite PK at table level. But, customer can update REVIEW_TEXT.

In Spring Data JPA, save() is working as update and insert both.

How can I update the REVIEW_TEXT using save() in this condition?

Comment: JPA API has no "save" method. Perhaps you ought to post actual CLASSES and PERSISTENCE CODE

Comment: Sorry, I meant JPA repository using Spring data.

Comment: Can you please post your entities and composite key class.